# How do you handle spacing from text to other UI elements?

Tags: guidelines, typography, space

I do not know how to handle spacing between text and other elements of the UI. If I want to separate my text from another element with a spacing of 16px should I start to measure from the end of the line height or from the text baseline?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no exact formula, it depends on the font size and mainly on the font type, in particular on the x-height since this determines the space occupied by the ascenders and descenders, which causes considerable space and optically distorts any measurement.

We can set certain parameters.

**Between a reading text block and an object**

From the baseline of the last line to the top edge of the object.

**Between two reading text blocks**

From the baseline of the last line to the x-height of the first line of the following paragraph.

[image]
**All caps Headlines**

From the headline baseline to the x-height of the first line of the following paragraph or the top edge of the next object:

[image: All caps]

---

So far so good, but the examples above use elements without too many conflicting components. Everything changes whith:

**Normal Headlines**

[image: Normal headlines]

**Normal Headlines in fonts with reduced x-height**

[image: Normal headlines 2]

Where the logical answer is to measure from the descender to the height of the x:

[image]

But optically that's not 16px, it's more than double:

[image: Optically double]

---

A possibility to find a similar measurement in all the elements of a project.

- Taking as a starting point the largest text or an upper-intermediate,
  for example a subtitle
- Check the font size, in the example, in addition to the ascenders and
  descenders, I placed the integral character `∫` which usually
  goes from the ascender's highest point to the bottom of the
  descenders
- Split the measurement into 5 or 6 modules to find the height/percentage that best suits the project

[image: Percentajes]

Use that percentage as the base module in the separations, in the example, 50% of the headline size (measured from the ascending to the descending)

[image]

The result by changing the sizes and fonts remains optically barely invariable:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to answer. It was really helpful!